# How can I export each row from a pandas (Python) DataFrame to separate .txt files?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to export a pandas DataFrame that is structured as following:

1. 2 columns, one is a customer ID, the other is a text string that contains all items purchased in the past month.
2. Each row represents a customer.

I want to export each row to a separate text file using pandas.

I am fairly new to Python, any insights are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your efforts so we can understand where you're stuck SO is not a code writing service

Answer (score 2):

You can try [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) your data and then use function [to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html). I omit index by parameter `index=False`.

```
print df
#   id   item
#0   1  item1
#1   1  item1
#2   1  item1
#3   2  item2
#4   2  item2
#5   3  item3

for name, group in df.groupby('id'): 
    group.to_csv(str(name) + '.txt', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) to iterate over each row of your data frame. Then simply write it in a new file.

A sample code looks like this:

```
d = your_pandas_dataframe
file = 'file{}.txt'

n = 0 # to number the files
for row in d.iterrows():
    with open(file.format(n), 'w') as f:
        f.write(str(row))
        n += 1
```

It will make 'file0.txt','file1.txt', ... etc. Each file contains one row of your data frame.